# How to determine if a series oscillates

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

I wanted to study the following series, $\sum (\frac{n^2+1}{n^2+2})^{n}x^n$ where $ x $ is a real number. Applying the root test, I found out that the series converges when $x \in ]-1,1[$ and that diverges when $x \geq 1$, but I can't figure out what happens when $x\leq -\$ could someone help me please?

Comment: Hint: What is the limit of $\left(\frac{n^2+1}{n^2+2}\right)^n$ ? How does this match up with conditions of alternating series test?

Comment: The value of that limit is 1, but $lim (-1)^n(\frac{n^2+1}{n^2+2})^n$ doesn't exist. I would like to apply Leibniz's theorem on oscillating series, but that one works when $lim a_n \neq 0$

Comment: Do you know what the alternating series test is? If you don't I would suggest looking it up. It gives clear conditions for convergence/divergence

Comment: Yes, I know that test, but I'm not interested in determine only if the series converges. I want to tell also when the series diverges/oscillates

Comment: What you're saying doesn't make sense. If it does not converge then it must diverge. The test doesn't just tell you when convergence happens, it also tells you when divergence happens.

Comment: @NinadMunshi: why does this have anything to do with alternating series test? That limit is not zero.

Comment: @GabrielePrivitera: your comment already shows that the series is not convergent at $x=-1$ by the necessary condition of convergent series.

Comment: @NinadMunshi "if it does not converge then it must diverge", this is true only if the terms of my sequence were always positive, but this doesn't happen since when $x\leq-1$ they are positive and negative, so the series can diverge (to $+\infty$ or $-\infty$?) or oscillate

Comment: @GabrielePrivitera: seriously, please review your book and note what radius of convergence for power series means. I am afraid you are making the problem unnecessarily complicated. Whether the series oscillates or not is not at all the point. Think about an example such as $\sum a_nx^n$ for $x=-2$. The necessary condition $\lim_{n}a_nx^n=0$ fails and it follows that $\sum a_nx^n$ cannot be convergent.

Comment: @squid "Whether the series oscillates or not is not at all the point" but that's the title of my question! I don't care if the series doesn't converge

Comment: Denote your power series as $\sum a_n x^n$.

The limit
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{a_n}=1
$$
tells you that the [radius of convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence) of the power series is $1$.

So it must diverge for $x$ with $|x|>1$. 

What you need to handle are the end-point cases $x=\pm 1$. 

Note that
$
a_n = \left(1-\frac{1}{n^2+2}\right)^n\tag{1}
$
and $\lim_{n}a_n\ne0$. This tells you that the series is not convergent at $x=1$. 

For $x=-1$, (1) implies that $\lim_n(-a_n)^n=0$ is impossible. Thus the series is neither convergent at $x=-1$.

Comment: I have deleted my answer since it is unclear what you are really asking. I leave the original answer in the comment box above. // "but I can't figure out what happens when `$x\leq -$` could someone help me please?" This is literally what you asked.

Answer (score 0):

It does the same thing as when $x\ge 1$, except it oscillates while it diverges. You can think of it as $\sum (\frac {n^2+1}{n^2+2})^n(-1)^n|x|^n$.

Comment: How do you prove that?

Comment: $|x| = -x, \forall x<0$. Thus $x = -|x|$ and $x^n = (-|x|)^n = (-1)^n|x|^n$

Answer (score 0):

Here, we shall study the absolute convergence because $x \in \mathbf{R}$. Si, let:
$$a_n=\left|\left(\frac{n^2+1}{n^2+2}\right)^{n}x^n\right|$$
We can use, now, the root-cryteria:
$$\lim_{n \to +\infty} \sqrt[n]{a_n}=\lim_{n \to +\infty}\left|\frac{n^2+1}{n^2+2}\cdot x\right|\sim\lim_{n \to +\infty}|x|$$
The root criteria ensure that $\sum a_n$ converges if and only if $|x| < 1 \implies -1 < x < 1$.

Now, we can consider $x \geq 1 \lor x \leq -1$. The necessary condition for the convergence is not satisfied, so the series diverges.

In conclusion:

1. $\sum_{n = 0}^{+\infty} (\frac{n^2+1}{n^2+2})^{n}x^n$ converges if and only $x \in (-1,1)$.
2. $\sum_{n = 0}^{+\infty} (\frac{n^2+1}{n^2+2})^{n}x^n$ diverges if and only if $x \leq -1 \lor x \geq 1$.